# Angular jasmine use same setup for different describes

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am trying to be able to set up same setups with testBed for different describes.

So lets say I have

```
file1.spec.ts

describe('file1Tests', () => {
    sameSetupMocksComponentsAndAllTheStuffButAlsoWithAccesibleProperties();
});

file2.spec.ts

describe('file2Tests', () => {
    sameSetupMocksComponentsAndAllTheStuffButAlsoWithAccesibleProperties();
});

file3.spec.ts

describe('file3Tests', () => {
    sameSetupMocksComponentsAndAllTheStuffButAlsoWithAccesibleProperties();
});
```

I cant really find a way how to do it.

Comment: You answered your own question :) put the code in an exported function and run it in whichever test file!

Comment: @NarenMurali but with this approach I need to recreate all variables mocks before each after each in every test so thats a plenty of code that will repeat. Is there some demo on how to do it?